# Probability of Two Coins (one fair and one biased)

Tags: probability

Two coins are in a hat. The coins look alike, but one coin is fair (with probability
1/2 of Heads), while the other coin is biased, with probability 1/4 of Heads. One of
the coins is randomly pulled from the hat, without knowing which of the two it is.
Call the chosen coin “Coin C”

- *Find the probability that in 10 flips of Coin C, there will be exactly 3 Heads. (The coin is equally likely to be either of the 2
  coins; do not assume it already landed Heads twice as in (a).)*

I have the following answers as shown below but I am  unsure what the 10 3 in brackets is? Thanks in advance

> Let $X$ be the number of Heads in 10 tossess.  By the Law of Total Probability (conditioning on which of the two coins is C)$$\begin{aligned}\mathsf P(X=3)~&=~\mathsf P(X=3\mid\text{fair})\,\mathsf P(\text{fair})+\mathsf P(X=3\mid\text{biased})\,\mathsf P(\text{biased})\\[2ex]&=~\dbinom{10}3\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\cdot\dfrac 12+ \dbinom{10}3\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^7\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\\[2ex]&=~\dfrac 12\dbinom{10}3\left(\dfrac 1{2^{10}}+\dfrac{3^7}{4^{10}}\right)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The "answers as shown below" aren't attached. Could you please attach them?

Comment: Calculate probability for each coin and then take the average

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XX25.png is the answers

Answer (score 3):

> I am unsure what the 10 3 in brackets is?

The binomial coefficient, $\tbinom{10}3$ is the count of distinct ways to select $3$ items from a set of $10$. Sometimes written as $^{10}\mathrm C_3$, it equals $\tfrac{10!}{3!~7!}$.

As such, it is the count for ways $3$ heads (and $7$ tails) may occur among the $10$ flips of coin C.  (IE: ways to select 3 from 10 flips to become the heads.)

Comment: Ahhh okay so (10 3) is the number of unique outcomes per-say, so for this given question it would be 120? Really appreciate your help!